DAX measure or calculated column for dynamical calculation of value based on date and ID
This is a Power BI question. I would like a solution with either a DAX measure or calculated column.
I have a table:



ID
Value
Date 1
Date 2
Value 2
Result




A
1000
08/12/2024
08/12/2024
-100
900


B
1200
08/12/2024
08/12/2024
-250
950


C
1500
08/12/2024
08/12/2024
0
1500


A
1000
08/12/2024
08/13/2024
-300
600


B
1200
08/12/2024
08/14/2024
50
1000


A
1000
08/12/2024
08/20/2024
0
600


C
1500
08/12/2024
08/20/2024
-500
1000



I want to add column "Result" for dynamically calculating the sum of "Value" and "Value 2" columns based on the "Date 2"(in ascending order) and corresponding "ID" columns. "Date 1" column will always be the same day (today) but it has duplicated IDs and Values. What I need is to calculate Result [1]= Value +Value 2 but then Rusult [2] = Result [1] + Value 2 [2].
Here is the screenshot of what the operations within the table should be like:
I have tried a few measures and tried looking up a similar question on Power BI forums but was not able to find anything like this.

Try this following as a Calculated Column:
Result = 
  var thisID = [ID]
  var thisDate2 = [Date 2]
  var totValue2 =
    CALCULATE(
      SUM([Value 2]),
      FILTER('YourTable', [ID] = thisID && [Date 2] <= thisDate2)
    )
  return [Value] + totValue2

